# Custom alt-tab application switcher in iTerm2 not responding

Tags: macos, iterm2, alt-tab

I got [alt-tab-macos](https://github.com/lwouis/alt-tab-macos): an awesome alt-tab application switcher for Mac OS, which separates application windows into different tiles. The reason being that I swapped my `control` and `command` keys (in `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Modifier keys`) and I am used to the "alt-tab" shortcut.

I also started to use iTerm2, but I noticed that this new alt-tab behavior is disabled when a iTerm2 window is active.

Has anyone experienced this? Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to override `Command` + `Tab` it to modify AltTab settings:

[image]

This should also resolve your issue with iTerm. Otherwise, check your iTerm profile setting - iTerm can consume your key stroke. `iTerm2` > `Preferences` > `Profiles` > `Default` or the other profile you use > `Keys` > `Left Option Key:`